# Refresh DataGridView on all open form when updating or inserted on another computer on the network

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have Server and three Computers

I want when one of the users add or delete data all three computers see all changes automatically at real time.

Right now when the user want to see any changes made by other users he has two options:

01-On a click of button

```
private async void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridControl1.DataSource =await paint.GetData1();
    gridControl4.DataSource =await paint.GetData2();
}
```

02-Close and Reopen the form

How can I do it?

Comment: if you not plannig to use TCP or UDP server or anything similar you cant. only thing you can do is query data frequently.

Comment: Yes, I plan to use TCP or UDP and I don't know which is better for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at a UDP broadcast to inform the other computers to update.
Here is a link to MS documentation on a simple use from both client & server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-udp-services?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thank you very much I have read the article and I will search more.
 What confused me is this sentence "UDP datagrams sent to the remote endpoint are not guaranteed to arrive, nor are they guaranteed to arrive in the same sequence in which they are sent".

Comment: It's just because UDP is a one-way protocol. Instead of a telephone it's a megaphone. You broadcast the message but they may not hear you and you have no way to know if they did. If concerned, you could broadcast the messages with unique IDs attached, but send each 2-3 times using the same ID. The receiving computers would just ignore multiple messages with the same ID, but you have multiple chances of your message being delivered.